# Core Data - How to do a SELECT DISTINCT specific columns! and preserve whole Table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to create a NSFetchRequest that produces results for a UITableView.

It should just find distinct 'partnerName' column.
then as a result of [this] rest of the columns will be produced. ( just most recenetly )

example)

partnerName ---------- Date

- A ------------------ 8/15
- A ------------------ 8/14
- B ------------------ 8/15
- B ------------------ 8/10
- C ------------------ 8/20

->

partnerName ---------- Date

- A ------------------ 8/15
- B ------------------ 8/15
- C ------------------ 8/20

  ```
          AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
          NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

          NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
          NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Chat" inManagedObjectContext:context];

          NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
          [request setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];

          [request setEntity:entity];
          [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
          [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"partnerName",nil]];


          [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

          // Execute the fetch
          __autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;

          NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
  ```

I don't know how to distinct 'Just a Column'- value. not whole data